# Grails: Using javascript to display results in same view

Tags: jquery, grails

I have two domains (models) Job and Results.
The Job page that lists jobs that have run and the Results page lists the results of the job.

What I want to do is combine these two pages so that the user stays on the one page.

My solution was to use remoteFunction, and I am close but am stuck on getting the data back from Grails. The code below calls my controller (method **doit**) and it returns a Groovy List:

```
...  
<g:render template="resulttable" />
<button id=show>show()</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#show").click(function () {
  // Returns Groovy List
  var results = <g:remoteFunction action="doit" id="${idx}" update="showit"/>  
  $(".resulttable").show('slow');
});
```

I am not a whiz with jQuery, so how do I process this results list? I have tried a half dozen different things and am stumped. I have a partial **resulttable** where I want to dislay the results. Or am I out in left field with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you necessarily need to use jQuery directly to do this.  You could set up your gsp like this:

```
<g:remoteLink action="doit" id="${idx}" update="showit"><button>show()</button></g:remoteLink>
<div id="showit">
</div>
```

And then in your controller you `doit` action:

```
def doit = {
    //find your list here
    def yourList = ...
    render(template: "resulttable", model: [listInTemplate: yourList])
}
```

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong, but this was not working for me yesterday. Tackled this again, and it worked - yea!