# Grails: Passing a javascript variable to a template

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

I am new to ajax so maybe this is obvious. I've tried many different not-working approaches. I have javascript that when you click on a button:

1. an ajax call that grabs some data from a controller - returns an object
2. display that data in a template that I will show on the page

Here is the javascript/ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#show").click(function () {
    $.ajax({  url: '/Myproject/result/index',
              type: "POST",
              data: { id: id},

          success: function(result) {
             alert("Success:" + result);  // Can see getting object back.
          }});
    $(".resulttable").show();
  });
```

Here is the key line in grails view template:

```
<g:each in="${allResults}" status="i" var="result">
```

1. How do I get the data from the javascript to the gsp code (ie allResults)?
2. Do I have to "refresh" this template to display new data?

thanks.

Comment: You asked almost the exact same question yesterday (11320173).  Did you read the answer I gave there?  There is a very simple way to do this.

Comment: I tried it the "simple" way you mentioned and no luck, so tried it this harder way. So, went back and tried the simple way after a day getting nowhere and it worked! yea! Thanks for gentle reminder. Sometimes you get so into a problem you make silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't make your javascript/jquery code populate things in the gsp, since the gsp is processed server-side and javascript is processed client-side, after the gsp rendered all html documents and populated them with your model. You need to be aware that your page was already processed, so things like ${variables} won't be reloaded anymore. So when you do this:

`$(".resulttable").show();`

It's not gonna show the result you're waiting for. You have to use javascript code to reload your result table.

So if you're using ajax here, you should use the function `success` to alter your html table via javascript/jquery since you already have the response you wanted. Maybe [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails11188/index.html) read can help you. Oh, and I think it would be better if in your ajax call, you would define a dataType (json works great in your case), like this:

```
$("#show").click(function () {
    $.ajax({  url: '/Myproject/result/index',
              type: "POST",
              data: { id: id},
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(result) {
                  alert("Success:" + result);  // Can see getting object back.
              }});
    $(".resulttable").show();
  });
```

Just to make clear what kind of response you're getting from the controller.

Comment: Thanks, kind of knew about the server-side/client side processing, but had not given it much thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write your ajax calls the hard way. There are some Grails intern tags you can use inside your html:

- http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html
- http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html
- http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html

Following the links you will find some nice examples...

Comment: I had tried these (no luck) and that is why I was trying this harder way. Silly me, went back to this method and al is well. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320173/grails-using-javascript-to-display-results-in-same-view)